# IOS 6 MPMoviePlayerController Rotation Issue

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, orientation

I have just updated to IOS 6 and now when I run my app the MPMoviePlayerControler shows the video incorrectly. The app is landscape but when the video is displayed in portrait. I have created new .h and .m files which is a child of MPMoviePlayerController. Here are my two files

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface TrashPackPlayer : MPMoviePlayerController

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TrashPackPlayer.h"

@implementation TrashPackPlayer

-(id)init{
    [super init];
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

I create the media player like this:

```
player = [[TrashPackPlayer alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sharedInfo.screenSize.width, sharedInfo.screenSize.height);
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    [player play];

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:player.view];
```

Is this correct?

What do I need to do to get this displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Rotations in iOS6 have changed dramatically, check the fourth point at:
http://megawertz.com/blog/2012/9/20/ios-6-and-rotation

The top-most view controller is in charge of setting the allowed orientations, subclassing a view controller is not going to solve your problem.